# How to keep subcomponent's data and status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here are my codes:

```
var Component_1 = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                subcomponents: []
            };
        },
        componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
            //push new subcomponent into 'subcomponents'
            this.state.subcomponents.push(nextProps.ele);
        },
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.state.subcomponents}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    // A router like that:
    var hash = window.location.hash
    if (hash === '#way1') {
        React.render( < Component ele={<SubComponent_1 />} /> , document.body);
    } else if (hash === '#way2') {
        React.render( < Component ele={<SubComponent_2 />} /> , document.body);
    } else {
        React.render( < Component ele={<SubComponent_3 />} /> , document.body);
    }
```

Code is simple : When location hash changed, rerender `<Component />` with new props of `ele` ( and the value of `ele` is a subcomponent ).

Every time rerender `Component` will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` and push `<Subcomponent_* />` into `subcomponents`.

So in a particular case,  `<Component />` might look like that:

```
<div>
    <SubComponent_1 />
    <SubComponent_2 />
</div>
```

My purpose is that : **How to keep the whole data (such as some data user typed into a `input` element) in  `<SubComponent_1 />`, when `<SubComponent_2 />` pushed into `subcomponents` and trigger `<Component />` rerender with two subcomponents?**

**UPDATE:**

When `<SubComponent_1 />` been removed in some way, how to keep the whole data of `<SubComponent_2 />`? I found add `key` prop to all subcomponent did not work.

Comment: Sorry, I have removed :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll want to use [react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) with some sort of flux implementation.

The router will handle all the `#` changes and [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) will keep your application state.

[Redux](http://rackt.github.io/redux/) is becoming very popular as a flux implementation.

There's plenty of resource out there for combining these things together:

- http://ngokevin.com/blog/redux-react-router/
- https://github.com/emmenko/redux-react-router-async-example
- https://github.com/rackt/redux-router

For your use case I'd suggest the following router config:

```
<Router>
  <Route path='/' component={Component}>
    <Route path='way1' component={SubComponent_1} />
    <Route path='way2' component={SubComponent_2} />
    <IndexRoute component={SubComponent_3} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Then in your `Component` render function you'll just need to include

```
{this.props.children}
```

Comment: I have using ```Backbone``` to handle hash change. Is there any way to achieve that without using flux?

Comment: flux handles storing the application state 'globally'; you can handle the routing however you wish.

Comment: Thanks, if I can't achieve that with raw js, I'll try flux :-)

Comment: A router will make your life a lot easier.